# Discord.js error "TypeError: channel.updateOverwrite is not a function"

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

When I'm trying to change the channel permissions to lock users from sending messages, this error pops up no matter what I do.

> TypeError: channel.updateOverwrite is not a function

Is there anything wrong?

```js
module.exports =
{
    async execute(message, args)
    {
            const role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === '@everyone')

            let channel = message.mentions.channels.first() || args[0]
            if(!channel) channel = message.channel

            if(channel.permissionsFor(message.guild.id).has('SEND_MESSAGES') === false) return message.channel.send(`${channel} is already locked.`)

            await channel.updateOverwrite(message.guild.id, { SEND_MESSAGES: false }).catch(() => {}) // Line in which the error happens
            await channel.updateOverwrite(role, { SEND_MESSAGES: false} ).catch(() => {})
    }
}
```

Comment: The error says `overwritePermissions` but your code says `updateOverwrite`?

Comment: Oops, I tried overwritePermissions to see if it fixed it and ended up using that error dump as the title, my bad!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're using discord.js v13 but using some old code. In v13 the `channel#updateOverwrite()` method is removed and while in previous version `channel#permissionOverwrites` was a [collection of overwrites](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=permissionOverwrites), in v13 it's a [`PermissionOverwriteManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=permissionOverwrites). It means, you should use its `.edit()` method to update overwrites:

```js
await channel
  .permissionOverwrites.edit(message.guild.id, { SEND_MESSAGES: false })
await channel
  .permissionOverwrites.edit(role, { SEND_MESSAGES: false })
```